# Time complexity of a simple Python function

Tags: python, time-complexity

I have been given a simply Python programme as such:

```
def boo(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return boo(n/2) + boo(n/2)
```

To boo, I have to find out the time complexity of the function. My idea is that since each `n` makes a call to two more `boo`'s, the time complexity is `O(2^n)`. However, it has been revealed that this is wrong. The answer has been revealed to me that the actual time complexity is O(n) without rationale given. My hunch is that `boo(n/2) + boo(n/2)` can be treated as `2*boo(n/2)`, but I am highly suspicious of this as I have seen similar scenarios before, and I vaguely remember that `boo(n/2) + boo(n/2)` cannot be equated to `2*boo(n/2)` in terms of processing steps.

What would be a more appropriate way to understand this? I am still struggling with the ideas in order of growth (space and time complexity), so if anyone has any general advice or material that can possibly help me, I greatly welcome them. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is closer to about O(log2(n))

Comment: If `n` is not a power of 2, this will recurse infinitely.

Comment: This may be naive, but it seems to me like `boo(2048)` calls `boo(1024)` twice, so doubling the input number doubles the number of operations. Which would make it O(n). Leaving aside the issue of using `/` instead of `//`.

Comment: @khelwood: Not naive, that's how it works. In raw calls, it always does `n * 2 - 1` total calls, which is `O(n)` overall.

Comment: `boo(n/2) + boo(n/2)` does `boo(n/2)` twice, while `2*boo(n/2)` does it only once, so clearly they can't be equally complex (unless that complexity is constant, but then it would be independent of `n`, so...).

Answer (score 3):

This code is `O(∞)`, as a non-power-of-two input will never complete (it will go from `> 1` to `< 1` without ever being `== 1`).

For powers of 2 (or if properly rewritten to do `boo(n // 2)` and not recurse infinitely), it's `O(n)`, as each step halves the input, but then does that halved work twice, leading to overall linear performance (to be precise, `boo` is called `2n - 1` times for `n` being a power of 2). Changing the final line to `return boo(n // 2) * 2` would get it to `O(log n)` performance.

Comment: I wonder if this was originally written for Python 2.x, which does integer arithmetic and will always reach 1.

Comment: @Barmar: That seems likely. It could be written with `//` in Python 2 as well though (`//` works long before it was required to achieve floor division) to make it portable. Either way, when it works as expected, the code is clearly `O(n)`.

Comment: Understood now! I suppose the code was written too simplistically. But now assuming that n is a power of 2, is it fair to say that, first, the time complexity of 2*boo(n/2) is O(logn) because we are "dividing and conquering" by a factor of 2. But in the case of boo(n/2) + boo(n/2), the operation is performed in 2 "branches", hence it becomes O(n). Is this a fair evaluation?

Comment: @a9302c: You got it. It's splitting the work in half, then doing that halved work twice, so it's just "doing the original work" in a funny way. If you like to think of it this way, it's doing `O(2 ** log₂n)` work (the log₂n from the halving, the `2**` from the doubling), which of course is equivalent to `O(n)`.